# SagePay Protocol banner not getting removed even after plugin upgrade in Magento

Tags: magento, protocols, upgrade, banner, opayo

I have just upgraded the SagePay plugin in Magento (version 1.5) from 2.23 to 3.00 using Ebizmarts plugin. Integration is successful and I can make payments. MySagePay is showing the transactions made from Magento store.
Both the Request and Response log of SagePaysuite show VPSProtocol=3.00.
Mode is LIVE and I am using Authorise and Capture.

Issue:
Even after successful(but 'this transaction has not been settled') transctions, the Protocol Banner in MySagePay still shows 'You will have to cease trading on this version (v2.23)'

Please suggest how this can be resolved?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend that you have a transaction ID (that you believe to be at 3.00) to hand and give Sage Pay a call - they can check the protocol value of a received transaction for you, so you can be sure you have upgraded successfully (MSP isn't always 100% reliable in the messages once you have upgraded!)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the reply. Yes, the issue got resolved after settlement of the latest(3.00) transactions after their Settlement Time.